# How to assign the delegate to the second view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uistoryboard

In a root view controller, when I click a button, the view controller push to a Category view controller and then it presents a Child view controller. When I selected a row, Child view controller dismiss and then back to Category and then back to root view controller. I have created a delegate in Child view controller, and root view controller conforms to this delegate. If the delegate is created in Category view controller, I can handle it. But it's created at Child view controller, it was presented by the Category view controller. So, how to assign this delegate to root view controller. The button which trigger the action is like this:

```
RootViewController.m

- (void)chooseCat:(BButton *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    CategoryViewController *cat = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cats"];
// How to create a instance of ChildViewController and assign ChildViewController's delegate to this RootViewController?
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cat animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways

1) **Delegate bridge**

Create delegate in `childView` which confirms to `CategoryVC`. Again create delegate in `CategoryVC` which confirms to `rootViewController`.

Then assign delegate for CategoryVC in rootViewController and delegate for childView in CategoryVC. And pass values or perform any action.

2) Using `NSNotificationCenter` which one is easiest.

Register Notification in `rootViewController` like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod) 
                                             name:@"myNotification"
                                           object:nil];

-(void)yourMethod
{

}
```

Use Notification from `childView` using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"myNotification" 
             object:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass ref of rootView controller to `CategoryViewController` and then again to `ChildViewController`, This way you can indirectly assign `delegate` for `rootViewController`.

If you have to pass from `chidViewController` to `rootViewController` then you can use `NSNotificationCenter` too. So need to pass ref...